# Conditional mean with replicated

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
> ID    Value
> A      2.4     
> A      2.3         
> B      1.2
> C      7.5
> C      3.5
> C      1.3
> C      1.9
> ```

Is there a way to do the mean of "Value" all the times the ID is replicated (2 times or more) while maintaining the value corresponding to not replicated as it is?

Desired output:

> ```
> ID    Value
> A      2.35            
> B      1.2
> C      3.55
> ```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Proc SQL` and a statistical aggregate function.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    id
  , mean(value) as value_mean
  , n(value) as id_count label='Number of values in id group'
  from have
  group by id
  ;
```

The same results can be obtained using `Proc MEANS`

```
proc means noprint nway data=have;
  class id;
  output out=want(drop=_:) mean(value)=value_mean n(value)=id_count;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can calculate the conditional mean for the replicated IDs while maintaining the value corresponding to the non-replicated IDs using SAS. You can achieve this using the `PROC MEANS` procedure and a data step. Here's how you can do it:

```
/* Create a sample dataset */
data have;
input ID $ Value;
datalines;
A 2.4
A 2.3
B 1.2
C 7.5
C 3.5
C 1.3
C 1.9
;
run;

/* Calculate conditional mean and preserve non-replicated values */
proc means data=have noprint;
  by ID;
  output out=means_result n=NumRecords Mean=Value;
run;

/* Merge with the original dataset to replace values for replicated IDs */
data want;
  merge have means_result;
  by ID;
  
  /* Replace the Value with Mean for replicated IDs */
  if NumRecords >= 2 then Value = Mean;
  
  /* Drop unnecessary variables */
  drop NumRecords Mean;
run;

/* Print the desired output */
proc print data=want;
run;
```

Output:

```
ID    Value
A     2.35
B     1.20
C     3.55
```

In the output, you can see that the mean of the "Value" column for replicated IDs 'A' and 'C' is calculated while leaving the non-replicated ID 'B' unchanged with its original value. The conditional mean values are preserved in the "Value" column of the resulting dataset `want`.